# Is "call" used copulatively in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, linking-verbs

There is a line in the movie [Goodfellas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodfellas):

> TOMMY (to Sonny): Jeez, it’s good you don’t mean to be out of order, Sonny. You **call embarrassing me** in front of my friends, calling me a fucking deadbeat, you know

It seems here *call* is used as a copula. Otherwise, this line is ungrammatical in standard English speech. Or is it a slang/dialectal usage?

Comment: The bolded phrase is not idiomatic English.

Comment: I think it might be a sentence fragment, like "You call embarrassing me in front of my friends *a good idea*"

Comment: @standgon is probably right.  You left something out. *You call this  soup?* means "This soup tastes awful. Do you really consider this slop [to be] soup?"  *You call this heap of metal a car?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"You call embarrassing me in front of my friends, calling me a fucking deadbeat, you know, [OK]?". The sentence seems to be **missing something** at the end. Regardless of that, one can analyse the first part of it as follows:

To call something something=to label something as something.

Example: He **called your opinion** uninformed. They **called our position** reasonable.

The verb call with the meaning "to label something as something" takes a direct object.

Gerund phrases as subjects:

**Driving cars** can be dangerous.

**Embarassing me** is a gerund phrase and **the phrase is the direct object of the verb call**.

**"You call embarrassing me in front of my friends** being nice?"

The rest of your sentence is probably just unfinished speech, a common thing that happens when we speak, but the clause is grammatical.

It is quite common to hear this phrasing: You call + gerund phrase X, where X can be an adjective, another gerund phrase or a noun.

- You call **acting so rude** OK?
- You call **telling him that** being truthful?
- You call **asking for help** idiocy?

Answer to the question: No, this is not the copulative use  of a verb, since the verb call here is taking a direct object and not linking one thing to another.

Comment: The implicit completion here is "You call embarrassing me in front of my friends (...) [*not being out of order?*]

Comment: There are any number of ways the utterance could be completed. Your guess is as good as mine. Since I do not have the script at hand, it is impossible to say categorically. [[side-issue: I ask fellow participants, is that statement by laugh2 in the comment ""categorical"?]]

Comment: The context of this sentence can be found [here](https://www.theringer.com/2016/9/19/16038510/goodfellas-funny-like-a-clown-speech-e919f46d9a23). The sentence may be competed in several ways, but this is the essence of the implicit message.

Comment: it's as I said in my answer, it is unfinished rhetorical-type question. Yes, it's meant negatively, but there is no *exact completion* one can propose, in my view.

Comment: I am not criticising your answer - I think it is very detailed and addresses the question directly and correctly. I just wanted to suggest an improvement by an alternative completion that, based on the context, is more likely than the [OK] in your answer.

Comment: There are tons of ways a trailing utterance could be completed. You imagined one of many possibilities. I merely put OK to be illustrative. Nothing else.